# Concatenating the Output of Two Java Variables together

Tags: java

I have this code, OCUOR is the output of IORNOa + the last 3 characters of the iCloc.

Is this code accurate to achieve this? Is the + correct syntax?

```
 oCUOR = iORNOa.trim() + iCLOC.substring(10, 3);
```

Comment: Debugger is your friend!

Comment: Well, does it compile? Have you tried creating unit tests to verify that it works as expected?

Comment: You might want to look at the docs for [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

Comment: Have you tried it and got an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? If yes, see [JavaDocs for `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), where the this statement is from: *`throws IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, **or beginIndex is larger than endIndex**.*

Answer (score 0):

It should be dynamic

```
oCUOR = iORNOa.trim() + iCLOC.substring(iCLOC.length()-4);
```

4 because index starts from 0, & no need to write last index as we are fetching till end